How can I optimize my Cloud Function to react to Firestore document status changes more efficiently?
How can I optimize my Cloud Function to react to Firestore document status changes more efficiently? Is there a way to make this process event-driven rather than using periodic checks? I'm looking for a method that minimizes Firestore reads/writes and reduces the latency and costs associated with polling.
Imagine that I launch a program and two processes are initiated:

The first process continuously checks if the status of a document has changed; if so, it stops the second process.
The second process launches the logic.

This is an example below :
// Firestore Trigger to monitor document changes
exports.monitorDocument = functions.firestore
    .document('myCollection/myDocument')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        // Check the updated document status
        const newValue = change.after.data();
        const oldValue = change.before.data();

        if (newValue.status !== oldValue.status) {
            console.log('Document status changed');
            // My logic
        }
    });

// Trigger to start the routine and manage the flow
exports.startRoutine = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('myCollection').doc('myDocument');

    // Routine
    try {
        const doc = await docRef.get();
        if (doc.exists && doc.data().status === 'active') {

            // My logic

            // After the routine, check the document again before moving to 'Execution'
            const updatedDoc = await docRef.get();
            if (updatedDoc.data().status === 'active') {
                console.log('Proceeding to execution');
                // Next logic
            } else {
                console.log('Status changed, halting execution');
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error:', error);
    }

    res.send('Process completed');
});

Any insights or examples of using another logic, Firestore triggers, or other Google Cloud services to manage such workflows would be greatly appreciated.

Cloud Functions are event driven.  They don't poll unless you somehow manage to write code in them to do polling.  I'm not clear what this polling is that you're referring to, or even what the problem is with what you have so far.  Your first function is only going to trigger when a matching document is updated, and the second one is only going to trigger when explicitly invoked. Please edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.

[ANSWER] I found a way.
I create a function  subscribeToDocument().
let yourObject = {};
const unsubscribe = await subscribeToDocument(myDocumentId, yourObject);

Then in the subscribeToDocument(), you will return a Promise, where there is a subscription to your document snapshot in it. You will pass the object with it, which you will use in your code to have real-time updates even during the execution of a loop.
async function subscribeToDocument(myDocumentId, yourObject) {
  const docRef = db.collection('your-collection name').doc('myDocumentId');

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = docRef.onSnapshot((docSnapshot) => {
      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        const data = docSnapshot.data();
        Object.assign(yourObject, data);
        resolve(unsubscribe);
      } else {
        reject(new Error("your error");
      }
    }, (error) => {
      unsubscribe();
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}

With this code, you will have real time update of your document during your program execution.
Don't forget to unsubscribe(); when you finish the execution.


Is there a way to make this process event-driven rather than using periodic checks?

Cloud Functions for Firebase are indeed event-driven and will always fire in response to events that happen in the Firebase products, like Firebase Authentication, Cloud Firestore, the Realtime Database or Cloud Storage.

I'm looking for a method that minimizes Firestore reads/writes and reduces the latency and costs associated with polling.

Cloud Functions for Firebase don't poll unless you write code in them that does polling.
Seeing your code, I can say that the first function will fire when a matching document is updated, while the second one will fire when it is explicitly invoked via HTTP.
When it comes to speed, I think that most likely you're experiencing a so-called cold start of the function. For more info, please see check the r resource below:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips


Hi Alex, thanks i found a way, I am writing the answer, thanks for asking
